# Correct way to Trigger Parent Entity UpdatedAt Refresh when Child Entity is Updated

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

In this scenario using EF I have an Author who has a 1 to N relationship with Articles. The requirement is that when an Article is updated the Author's UpdatedAt timestamp should reflect the change. Now the brute force way would be to load the Author and do a dummy Save when I'm updating an Article. That seems very inefficient. Is there a best practice approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming we have the following Model:

```cs
public class Author
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AuthorValue { get; set; } = null!;

    public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }

    public List<Article> Articles { get; set; } = new();
}

public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ArticleValue { get; set; } = null!;

    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Then we can override `SaveChanges/Async` and intercept modification of Article table.  If `Author` is not loaded, new entry will be attached and single property marked as modified.

```cs
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Author> Authors => Set<Author>();
    public DbSet<Article> Articles => Set<Article>();

    private void HandleChanges()
    {
        var authorsToUpdate = ChangeTracker.Entries<Article>()
            .Where(a => a.State == EntityState.Added || a.State == EntityState.Modified || a.State == EntityState.Deleted)
            .Select(a => (a.Entity.AuthorId, a.Entity.Author))
            .Distinct();

        foreach (var pair in authorsToUpdate)
        {
            if (pair.Author != null)
            {
                // Author already loaded and we can update this record
                pair.Author.UpdatedAt = DateTime.Now;
            }
            else
            {
                // add fake record just for update
                var author = new Author { Id = pair.AuthorId, UpdatedAt = DateTime.Now };
                Attach(author);
                Entry(author).Property(x => x.UpdatedAt).IsModified = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public override int SaveChanges(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
    {
        HandleChanges();
        return base.SaveChanges(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess);
    }

    public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        HandleChanges();
        return base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: This violates the single responsibility principle. Your db context shouldn't take care of updating unrelated entities imo. Also fetching the list on each update (regardless of updated entity) feels a bit heavy handed.

Comment: @display-name, I do no care which it violates, It's just requirement. *Also fetching the list on each update* - what? You can do that faster?

Comment: Ok, let's say your application grows and you have 10 other entities that should have this kind of update functionality. How would your `handleChanges` method look? Do you load a list for each of those entities? I'm genuinely curious. I don't see how this scales.

Comment: @display-name, this code do not load anything. It tracks already loaded entities. It is faster than what `SaveChanges` do for detecting changes in all already loaded entities.

Answer (score 1):

Don't now if it is best practice, this is my way to do that.
I use a Interface in Entity for that and override DbContext SaveChangesAsync Methode.
You can also write Interfaces for insert, delete.

```
    public interface IBeforeUpdate
    {        
        void BeforeUpdate();
    }
```

```
    public class TestDbContext : DbContext
    {        
        public TestDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public List<IBeforeUpdate> GetModifiedBeforeUpdateEntites() => ChangeTracker
            .Entries()
            .Where(it => it.State == EntityState.Modified && it.Entity is IBeforeUpdate)
            .Select(it => (IBeforeUpdate)it.Entity)
            .ToList();

        public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken)) 
        {            
            DoBeforeUpdate();
            return base.SaveChanges();
        }

        private void DoBeforeUpdate()
        {
            List<IBeforeUpdate> modifiedEntites = GetModifiedBeforeUpdateEntites();
            foreach (IBeforeUpdate entity in modifiedEntites)
            {
                entity.BeforeUpdate();
            }
        }
    }
```

```
    public class Article : IBeforeUpdate
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }

        public Author Author { get; set; }

        public BeforeUpdate()
        {
            Author.UpdatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "dummy save", but this is how we do it:

1. Our DBContext has a generic Audit function which changes the Audit-Properties of our AuditableEntities depending on their tracked state.

```cs
// DbContext.cs

public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
{
  await Audit();
  return await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}

private async Task Audit()
{
  foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<AuditableEntity>())
  {
    switch (entry.State)
    {
      case EntityState.Added:
        entry.Entity.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
        entry.Entity.CreatedBy = await _currentUserService.GetUserName();
        break;
      case EntityState.Modified:
        entry.Entity.ChangedOn = DateTime.Now;
        entry.Entity.ChangedBy = await _currentUserService.GetUserName();
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

2. If we want to update the "modified" fields of a parent entity we manually set its state:

```cs
// Repository.cs

public Task MarkAsModifiedAsync(Foo foo)
{
  _dbContext.Entry(foo).State = EntityState.Modified;
  return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

No reason to add fake data or fake a real save. Just a clean way to manually mark any entity as modified and update its audit fields on save.

Looking at this from a design / architecture point of view I'd say that loading the parent and explicitely updating it is almost always a better choice than hiding this in some other unrelated area.

If you are changing its children and this change should also trigger an update to the parent, then your code should reflect that.

The accepted answer is problematic, because the DbContext now implicitely modifies data and doesn't even do so in a generic way. If you want to add more entities with the same structure in the future your DbContext will be start to bloat.